# Trade Pokemon RetroPie

Tags: retropie

I just got my Retropie Up and running, and I am playing Pokemon Red. when I use TGB-Dual to launch the Rom, I cannot load my savings in the second screen.

Did anyone manage to make the link in tgb Dual work to trade Pokemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in retropie from the answer I found here: http://libretro.com/forums/showthread.php?t=6507&p=43843#post43843

As a workaround, I took my save file, renamed it to a .sav, and then used TGB Dual 8 on a PC to trade. Then renamed save file to .srm and moved back to retropie. It's a pain but it was worth it for the Gengar!

TGB Dual 8: http://digiex.net/downloads/download-center-2-0/nintendo-game-boy-content-gb-gbc-gba/apps/14666-tgb-dual-vol-8-3-1-english-download-gameboy-emulator-link-cable-support.html

This guide was also useful for TGB Dual: 
https://forums.emulator-zone.com/showthread.php?t=22770